# Autofixture.Automoq - generics make bool always true

Tags: c#, generics, moq, autofixture, automoq

```
public interface IResult
{
    bool Success { get; } 
}

public interface IResult<T> : IResult
{

}
```

Using AutoFixure, and AutoMoq I am trying to find a way to to make `Success` always `true`, no matter what type `T` is. Registering a fake is easy enough with `IResult`, but that doesn't seem to work for `IResult<T>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a fake implementation

```
public class FakeResult<T> : IResult<T> {
    public bool Success {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

along with adding a `TypeRelay` customization

```
 fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IResult<>), typeof(FakeResult<>)));
```

All calls for `IResult<>` will use the `FakeResult<>` which has its `Success` to return `true`no matter what is the type of `T`.

Full example to test that the mock works as intended.

```
[TestClass]
public class AutoFixtureDefaultGeneric {
    [TestMethod]
    public void AutoFixture_Should_Create_Generic_With_Default() {
        // Arrange
        Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IResult<>), typeof(FakeResult<>)));

        //Act
        var result = fixture.Create<IResult<string>>();

        //Assert
        result.Success.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```